# Why is select:-moz-focusring not removing Firefox dotted lines in this bootstrap nav bar?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I want to get rid of the Firefox dotted lines in my bootstrap navigation bar.

I have read in many places that adding this to the CSS file will get rid of them:

```
    a:-moz-focusring {
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
    }
```

But in the following code they still appear. Does anyone know why?

```
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
                display: none !important;
            }    
            select:-moz-focusring {
                color: transparent;
                text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>    
    <body ng-cloak ng-controller="mainController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-brand">AngularJS Routing</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>        

        <script>
                            var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
                            mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                                $routeProvider
                                        .when('/', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
                                            controller: 'mainController'
                                        })
                                        .when('/about', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/about.htm',
                                            controller: 'aboutController'
                                        })
                                        .when('/contact', {
                                            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.htm',
                                            controller: 'contactController'
                                        });
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.message = 'the home page';
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.message = 'the about page';
                            });
                            mainApp.controller('contactController', function ($scope) {
                                $scope.message = 'the contact page';
                            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did u try `outline: none;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work — you should be using the standard `:focus` pseudo-class unless you have a very good reason to use the non-standard `:-moz-focusring`:

```
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

`color` and `text-shadow` affect text, not the focus outline, so those won't work. Even [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring) does not show any examples using those properties, instead using `outline`. All that said, it is still preferable to use `:focus`.

But the actual problem here is that you're including Bootstrap after your `<style>` elements. Bootstrap has an `a:focus` rule that enables the focus outline, which overrides your CSS since it's being included later. Moving it above your `<style>` elements will fix this:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }    
    a:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In general, it is a good idea to have any `<link>` and `@import` statements before `<style>` elements, so that the linked stylesheets won't inadvertently override your internal CSS (specificity notwithstanding).

Comment: Thanks, the order in HEAD was the problem, and all that was needed was a:focus.